# How to show that multi-dependent optional forms are linked together without hiding?

Tags: usability, gui-design, user-expectation, usability-testing, ux-designer

So I am creating a form with 3 optional items that are dependent on one another. The first is date. If the user adds a date, they have the option to add an alert time. Once they select a time, they can add multiple alert times if they wish. Once they add an alert time, they have the option to add additional time and/or set a repeat setting. Additionally, once the user sets a time, they have the option to select their alert settings (sound, vibration, sound + vibration) Currently, I have them disabled until the dependent form has an input. My problem is, I feel that this is too cluttered and makes my overall form a bit longer than intended. I would prefer not to hide the items since they let the user know about the alert functionality, but I feel that having the disabled features take up a lot of space. To clarify, "alert" will be available when "date is input. "Repeat" and "Sound" will be available once an alert is input. Date and alert are optional, but if an alert is input, then repeat and sound must have at least the default value shown.

[image]

Edit: Once repeat is enabled, repeat will also have additional options i.e. when "weekly" is selected, additional options like "days of the week selector" would pop up. I left that part out to simplify the problem, but it is something to consider.

[image]

Comment: Is there a specific product reason why you can't hide anything? The alert 'repeat' and sound features are fairly standard, so it doesn't seem like they would miss out on not seeing the alert repeat and details at first.

Comment: @MikeM Not necessarily, but this information is in an overlay with only 3 required inputs. The date, alert and all other inputs are optional. I thought because there are so many optional options, if I hide them and the user slowly discovers them as they input their info, the overlay would get bigger and bigger. I was not sure if a dynamically sized overlay would be ideal. Every time a hidden option would appear, all items would shift up and the layout. I added an additional image for clarity